# Error deploying with sveltekit-adapter-aws

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

Trying to deploy a sveltekit app using sveltekit-adapter-aws

```
import { adapter } from 'sveltekit-adapter-aws';
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';

const config = {
preprocess: vitePreprocess(),
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter({
            autoDeploy: true
        })
    }
};
```

aws credentials are correctly set

but I'm getting this error when i run 'npm run build'

❌ Building assets failed: Error: Building Assets Failed: Error: sveltekit-adapter-aws-webapp: SSM parameter /cdk-bootstrap/hnb659fds/version not found. Has the environment been bootstrapped? Please run 'cdk bootstrap' (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/bootstrapping.html)
at buildAllStackAssets (/Users/git/test/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/build.ts:21:11)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at CdkToolkit.deploy (/Users/git/test/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/cdk-toolkit.ts:197:9)
at initCommandLine (/Users/git/test/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/cli.ts:364:12)

Building Assets Failed: Error: sveltekit-adapter-aws-webapp: SSM parameter /cdk-bootstrap/hnb659fds/version not found. Has the environment been bootstrapped? Please run 'cdk bootstrap' (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/bootstrapping.html)

I also ran this cdk bootstrap...